# Create Jenkins Job that searches for strings in files and reports warnings with file and line number

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I have Builds in Jenkins that produce warnings. These are great to navigate and address issues. I want to search in the source for strings and report these using the same warning style and, therefore, warning navigator. I have looked at the text finder plugin but this is a post build step that appears to only effect success or failure. I have looked at power shell but I do not see anything that will produce a warnings with a path and a line number. I could use powershell, batch file, or even write a small command line app to do this. I'm hoping something already exists.

Update:
This looks the best suggestion so far...

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem \ExampleFolder\ -Recurse; foreach ($file in $files) { $File | select-string ExampleString | % {Write-Warning "$($file.fullname): $($_.linenumber)"}}
```

I have not had time to try this in Jenkin's PowerShell plugin yet. Works great from a script. May need to change format to match expectations of Jenkins's warnings plugin. Have not worked out if I can search for strings containing punctuation. For example "`(void)`". Also need to limit to only source files with extension `.c` or , `.h`

Comment: What is the question and where is the code you have issues with? Maybe have a refresher on how to create a [minimal, complete and variviable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you looking for the `Select-String` cmdlet for which the output has the `linenumber` property?

Comment: @BenH yes. That sounds like it could be integrated into a Jenkins job as it appears to have PowerShell support. I'm looking for an output format that the warnings plugin will parse and understand. I guess producing a warning like a C compiler would work. These include file and line number etc. So it would be nice to have some control over the format, unless it happens to be in a format that is already parseable by the warnings plugin.

Comment: Not exactly sure the format to parse or the exact stream the plugin is looking for. But how about something like this: `$Files = Get-ChildItem \ExampleFolder\ -Recurse; foreach ($file in $files) { $File | select-string ExampleString | % {Write-Warning "$($file.fullname): $($_.linenumber)"}}`

Comment: You can limit by extension with the `-Filter` property on [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1). And yes you can have punctuation but [`Select-String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1) uses regex by default so you would need to escape the characters manually with a \ or you could use the `Escape` method of the `[regex]` class to do it. e.g. `[regex]::escape('(void)')` or use `-simplematch` on the select-string